# Does the Xbox 360 wireless controller for Windows work with the Xbox 360?

Tags: xbox-360, controllers

As the title states, does the [Xbox 360 wireless controller for Windows](http://www.microsoft.com/hardware/en-us/p/xbox-360-wireless-controller-for-windows) work wirelessly with an Xbox 360?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes.

From the details tab of the page you linked:

> For PC and Xbox 360
>
> Works across Microsoft's gaming platforms. Xbox 360 Controller for Windows works with most Windows 8 PCs and Xbox 360, delivering a consistent and universal gaming experience.